# How can I test for multiple classes at once using React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to check whether a DOM element has some specific classes or not. I know I can do this:

```
test('My element has correct classes assigned', () => {
    const myElement = screen.queryByText('This is my element');

    expect(myElement).toHaveClass('class-one');
    expect(myElement).toHaveClass('class-two');
});
```

I wonder if something like the following is possible too because my code is getting quite repetitive...

```
test('My element has correct classes assigned', () => {
    const myElement = screen.queryByText('This is my element');

    expect(myElement).toHaveClasses(['class-one', 'class-two']); // pseudo-code
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve that by simply passing multiple classes to the toHaveClass method as an array or comma-separated values.

Example with an array:

```
test('My element has correct classes assigned', () => {
    const myElement = screen.queryByText('This is my element');

    expect(myElement).toHaveClass(['class-one', 'class-two']);
});
```

Example with comma-separate values:

```
test('My element has correct classes assigned', () => {
    const myElement = screen.queryByText('This is my element');

    expect(myElement).toHaveClass('class-one', 'class-two');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @ThomasSquall mentioned `toHaveClass` accepts a list of classnames to test.

A more general approach for this (no matter which API you are using) is to use standard JS constructs in your unit tests.

For example you could do something like this:

```
['class-one', 'class-two'].forEach(className => {
   expect(myElement).toHaveClass(className)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for a proper Jest solution not a JS workaround.

Comment: In that case @ThomasSquall's answer is what you are looking for

Comment: I know, gonna accept in a second.